# Screen scraping, forms authentication

Tags: oracle, forms-authentication, screen-scraping, web-scraping, oracleforms

I am trying to do some screen scraping accessing a forms authenticated website. I was doing some tests on an asp.net forms authenticated site that I built and it worked just great. When I tried the real site I realized it was using some kind of an Oracle forms authentication (a fiddler showed a call to a dll instead of an html file. I suppose this dll provides the html result). What I see in fiddler is:

```
https://{domain}/access/oblix/apps/webgate/bin/webgate.dll
```

The rest of the call seems similar, cookie, user name and password, just like in the regular forms authentication.
Any idea on how to crack this type of request (to a dll instead of an html)?
(By the way, the result I get is some kind of an Oracle error).

Answer (score 1):

With Forms Authentication the webserver issues the client with a cookie that is used to verify the client in future subsequent requests (HTTP Basic and Digest authentication requires the client to post the "WWW-Authorization" header on every request). Are you persisting your cookies between requests?

Comment: I do preserve the cookie. (It is also working for me with an asp.net forms authentication site, so my method is OK). My problem is the request for the dll in the background, instead of the html page

Answer (score 1):

The file extension of the url is not important to how you make your request.
It sounds like your script needs to make a request identical to the ajax request made by your browser (and shown in fiddler).